# Uncaught TypeError: this.state.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, axios, state

In React, I'm using Axios to map an array to output a list of movie names that are pulling from the MovieDB API. It connects to the MovieDB just fine, however, I get the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.state.movies.map is not a function

I believe this is preventing the movie list from outputting to the browser.

Codesandbox link is [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-project-beer-api-zeqk4?fontsize=14).

Here's the SearchBar component where the code lies:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
    import axios from "axios";

    import "../SearchBar/_search-bar.scss";

    class SearchBar extends Component {
      state = {
        userSearchTerm: "",
        movies: []
      };

      // When user types, match the value to state
      onInputChange = e => {
        this.setState({ userSearchTerm: e.target.value });
      };

      // On submitting the input, grab the API
      onInputSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const movieName = this.state.userSearchTerm;
        const KEY = "XXXXXXXXXX";

        const searchQuery = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${KEY}&language=en-US&query=${movieName}&page=10`;

        axios.get(searchQuery).then(res => {
          this.setState({ movies: res.data });
        });
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.onInputSubmit}>
              <TextField
                label="Search for a movie and hit enter..."
                margin="normal"
                className="search-bar"
                onChange={this.onInputChange}
              />
            </form>
            <ul>
              {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
                <li key={movie.id}>{movie.results.title}</li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default SearchBar;
```

On a side note, I tested out this same code, but with a different API and it worked just fine. Is there something wrong with the API itself or the this.state.movies.map?

Comment: what does `res.data` look like?

Comment: Did you mean to publish your API key to everyone?

Comment: When I add console logs to your get request to view what res is getting back it gets nothing. So you may want to look at your url and verify that it is correct first

Comment: Object {data: Object, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, config: Object…}
data: Object
page: 10
total_results: 47
total_pages: 3
results: Array[0]
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
headers: Object
config: Object
request: XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A working code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import axios from "axios";

import "../SearchBar/_search-bar.scss";

class SearchBar extends Component {
  state = {
    userSearchTerm: "",
    movies: []
  };

  // When user types, match the value to state
  onInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({ userSearchTerm: e.target.value });
  };

  // On submitting the input, grab the API
  onInputSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const movieName = this.state.userSearchTerm;
    const KEY = "XXXXXX";

    const searchQuery = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${KEY}&language=en-US&query=${movieName}&page=10';

    axios.get(searchQuery).then(res => {
      console.log("res is ------", res)
      this.setState({ movies: res.data.results });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onInputSubmit}>
          <TextField
            label="Search for a movie and hit enter..."
            margin="normal"
            className="search-bar"
            onChange={this.onInputChange}
          />
        </form>
        <ul>
          {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
            <li key={movie.id}>{movie.original_title}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

**You should use** `this.setState({ movies: res.data.results });` and `<li key={movie.id}>{movie.original_title}</li>`

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working.

Quick question, is there a reason I need to use 'res.data.results' versus 'res.results'?

Comment: @JDFill because the movies are coming in `res.data.results` from API.

Comment: axios results come back as an object with multiple keys, `data` is the key response body returned. There are other keys which are used less often if you need to access response headers or other data about the request.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#response-schema

Answer (score 4):

The API you are using is returning an object with "results" being the key you are looking for. If you update your setState to `this.setState({ movies: res.data.results });` you should get what you are looking for.

[Axios Response Schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#response-schema)

As a side note I would guard your map function with something like `{Array.isArray(this.state.movies) && this.state.movies.map(movie => (...` this will conditionally render the output only once `movies` is set in state and is an array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
You need to change the setState call to this:
this.setState({ movies: res.data.results });

The response is not an array, it is an object like this:

{
  "page": 10,
  "total_results": 136643,
  "total_pages": 6833,
  "results": [
    {
      "vote_count": 110,
      "id": 13189,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7.3,
      "title": "A Christmas Carol",
      "popularity": 6.52,
      "poster_path": "/m3T3iLdE6J5PrqvvP0XNHBvM2bm.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "A Christmas Carol",
      "genre_ids": [
        18,
        10751,
        14,
        10770
      ],
      "backdrop_path": "/gaTpxTYQMGoagtMVYK8F7SjqTGM.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "An old bitter miser who makes excuses for his uncaring nature learns real compassion when three ghosts visit him on Christmas Eve.",
      "release_date": "1984-12-17"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 419,
      "id": 12103,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.1,
      "title": "Don't Say a Word",
      "popularity": 9.995,
      "poster_path": "/qx3hgW9MqxsEEFjx4eSbpp1Fe2l.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Don't Say a Word",
      "genre_ids": [
        53
      ],
      "backdrop_path": "/AaOtoMzqWJPSNXPRKwbvqf6MbKo.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "When the daughter of a psychiatrist is kidnapped, he's horrified to discover that the abductors' demand is that he break through to a post traumatic stress disorder suffering young woman who knows a secret..",
      "release_date": "2001-09-28"
    }
  ]
}
```